# How to cast string to int

Tags: c#

I have a set of objects named something like this:

```
_1,_2,_3 .... _n
```

Isn't an array, just a bunch of objects uinto  a custom control. I want to cast the name to an int. first I remove `_`, but If use

```
    private void Superficie_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Shape myShape = ((Shape)sender);
        string lcNombre = myShape.Name.Remove(0, 1);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Those are my tryes  
        // Doesn't work because it must expect a nullable value 
        index = lcNombre as decimal; 

        // Doesn't work  Can't convert string to int
        index = (int)lcNombre;
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------


        if (index > 0)
        {
            bool lIsSelected =  !Pieza.Superficies.Where(x=>x.Id == index).First().IsSelected;
            Pieza.Superficies.Where(x => x.Id == index).First().IsSelected = lIsSelected;

            if (lIsSelected)
                myShape.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(SystemColors.HotTrackColor);
            else
                myShape.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(SystemColors.ControlLightLightColor);
        }
    }
```

How can I do to cast it ?

Comment: I must be losing it.  Time to go to bed ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way is

```
index = int.Parse(lcNombre);
```

If you're not completely sure whether lcNombre is really an integer, you can use instead

```
int result;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(lcNobre, out result);
```

or in newer versions of .NET, you can declare the output variable like:

```
bool isInt = int.TryParse(lcNobre, out var result);
```

Finally you can use

```
index = Convert.ToInt32(lcNobre);
```

This approach (like int.Parse()) will throw a FormatException if the input value is not convertible to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Convert` static methods:

```
index = Convert.ToInt32(lcNombre);
```

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

Error wise.. you may want to use `TryParse`.. as it returns true or false depending on a successful conversion:

```
int index;

if (int.TryParse(lcNombre, out index)) {
    // conversion successful
}
else {
    // couldn't convert
}
```

MSDN Link for `int.TryParse`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int result=0;
Int32.TryParse(lcNombre,out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to do this is to make an extension method as follows

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int? AsInteger( this string str)
    {
        int value;
        if ( int.TryParse( str, out value ) )
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can this

```
index = lcNombre.AsInteger() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strArr[] = myShape.Name.Split('_',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

int num;
int.TryParse(strArr[0],num);
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer?